Understanding Coordinate Charts in Non-Parametric Statistical Manifolds
I'm studying the construction of non-parametric statistical manifolds and I'm having trouble understanding the intuition behind the coordinate chart construction, particularly the role of Orlicz spaces. Here's what I understand so far:
Given a measure space $(X, \mathcal{X}, \mu)$, we define:
\begin{align*}
M_\mu &= \{p : X \to \mathbb{R} \text{ measurable} : p > 0 \text{ } \mu\text{-a.e.}, \int p d\mu = 1\} \\
L^{\Phi_1}(p \cdot \mu) &= \text{Orlicz space with Young function } \Phi_1(x) = \cosh(x) - 1 \\
B_p &= \{u \in L^{\Phi_1}(p \cdot \mu) : E_p[u] = 0\} \\
V_p &\subset B_p \text{ (open unit ball in } B_p\text{)}
\end{align*}
The coordinate chart is constructed as follows:

Define $e_p : V_p \to M_\mu$ as $e_p(u) = \exp(u - \log E_p[\exp(u)]) \cdot p$
Let $U_p$ be the range of $e_p$
Define $s_p : U_p \to V_p$ as $s_p(q) = \log(q/p) - E_p[\log(q/p)]$

My questions are:

Why is the Orlicz space $L^{\Phi_1}(p \cdot \mu)$ used here instead of a more familiar space like $L^2(p \cdot \mu)$? What properties of the Orlicz space are crucial for this construction?

How does the choice of the Young function $\Phi_1(x) = \cosh(x) - 1$ affect the structure of the manifold? What would change if we used a different Young function?

In the parametric case (e.g., normal distributions), we map directly from the distribution to its parameters. Here, it seems we're mapping from $V_p$ to $M_\mu$ and then back to $V_p$. What's the intuition behind this "round trip"?

How does this construction provide a coordinate system for $M_\mu$? I'm struggling to see how elements of $V_p$ act as coordinates for probability densities.

In the parametric case, the dimension of the coordinate space is clear (e.g., 2 for normal distributions). Here, both $M_\mu$ and $V_p$ seem infinite-dimensional. How do we interpret this in terms of coordinates?

How does the measure $p \cdot \mu$ used in the Orlicz space relate to the original measure $\mu$ on $X$? Why is this change of measure necessary?


I'd appreciate any insights that could help me understand this construction better, especially in terms of how it provides a workable coordinate system for the space of all probability distributions and the role of Orlicz spaces in this framework. Thank you!

This is not something I'm very familiar with, and the notation is a bit odd to me, but here's my best shot.
The Orlicz space and Young function are selected so as to ensure $E_p[\exp(u)]<\infty$ for $u$ in the open unit ball $V_p$ around $p$. Note that the Young function increases like $e^{|x|}$ as $|x|\rightarrow\infty$.
The construction used is similar to that of exponential families of distributions: ie where you take a probability density $p(x)$, eg with $x\in\mathbb R^d$, and create a family $p_u(x)$ of distributions parametrised by vectors $u\in\mathbb R^d$ by
$$
p_u(x) = e^{u\cdot x - m_p(u)}p(x)
\quad\text{where}\quad
m_p(u) = \ln E_p\left[e^{u\cdot X}\right].
$$
Note that the cumulant generating function $m_p(u)$ is just a normalization factor to make give it measure 1.
For a probability distribution like $p(x)=C/(1+x^2)$, this type of construction would fail since $\int e^{ux}/(1+x^2)\,dx$ is infinite for all $u\not=0$.
I suggest you read up a little on exponential families (in this case the Wikipedia page would be a bad tutor) where it becomes more clear how this is a parametrisation, ie coordinate system, of a family of distribution.
Working with infinite dimensional vector spaces and manifolds may take a little getting used to in terms of intuition, but a lot of the maths will be just the same. If you have some familiarity with functional analysis, that would probably help: here you work with infinite dimensional vector spaces containing functions.
The choice of Orlicz space and Young function thus provide criteria to ensure distributions included are well-behaved, but does not otherwise influence the internal geometry: at least not if you think in terms of it as a Fisher manifold. But different criteria may restrict the manifold to a subspace/submanifold.
The map $s_p$ is just the inverse map of $e_p$: set $q=e_p(u)$ and solve to retrieve $u$. Note that this exploits $E_p[u]=0$ to retrieve $m_p(u)=\ln E_p[e^u]=-E_p[\ln(q/p)]$.
The measure $\mu$ determines eg if the distributions have point probabilities or continuous probabilities: like the standard measure on $\mathbb R$ versus the point count measure on natural numbers $\mathbb N_0\subset\mathbb R$. You could have used a probability density function $p(x)\,dx$ or probabilities $p_x$ for $x\in\mathbb N_0$ instead, but the $p\cdot\mu$ way of formulating it covers both.

Thanks. I will look into the references you have given
